# Footer at Bottom of Screen rather than bottom of page

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to use OOP to design my site. I have a function that calls each part of my page content navbar, body and footer. I notice that no matter what I do the footer stays at the bottom of screen instead of the bottom of the page. see image below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXLLF.png)
this is how i call my page contents

```
public function  run()
{
  echo $this->getHTML_Header().          
         $this->getMainStyles().$this->getBootstrapScript().$this->getBootstrapStyles().
           $this->getCloseHTML_Header().
            $this->getMainScript().
              $this->getNavBar().
               $this->getSlider().
               $this->getBlogPosts().
       $this->getFootBar(); 
}
```

Comment: This is more an issue with the HTML/CSS of your page. Check that the CSS for the footer does not position it absolutely or fixed.

Comment: It would help if you post the whole css and html, and also describe or post images of the whole browser window with the current behaviour and the desired behaviour, so we can understand better what you mean.